# How to search, find and print indexes of a word given by the user?

Tags: c, string, search, indexing

1. Accept a paragraph from user.
2. count number of words and characters
3. Searches a word given by the user in the paragraph and prints out the indexes of that word.

I have done 1 and 2, need help with 3.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char str[200];
    char search[20];
    int i,c1=0,c2=0;

    printf("enter the paragraph\n");
    gets(str);
    for (i = 0;str[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        c1++;
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            c2++;    
    }
    printf("number of characters in given paragraph: %d\n", c1);
    printf("number of words in given paragraph: %d\n", c2+1);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: `int main(void)`. `gets`'s dead, use `fgets`.

Comment: `Count        words                  in        this          sentence` with your algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

- have an array of char pointers in which you record the starting point of each word. Say you call it `char *words[20];`. In your for loop, record the beginning of each word. When you see a space (a word separator), replace it with a `'\0'`.
- set the first `word` not in use to 0 so you can know later you have gone through the array of words in use.
- ask the word to search for and do a loop checking each word against the word to search
- print the index where the word is found.